# MMDrawerController having slider on each View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, slider, drawer, mmdrawercontroller

I am using `MMDrawerController` for making left slide menu in **iOS**. The problem is that all the view controllers I am using in this project are having `slider` with them i.e in each `UIViewController` I can slide to get left menu but I want only with the first view not with all the `UIViewController`.

How can I stop slider code for the other `UIViewController` in the project.

Answer (score 0):

you can cancel panning using below method. put that method in viewWillAppear

To allow gesture add this in `viewWillAppear`

```
[self.mm_drawerController setOpenDrawerGestureModeMask:MMOpenDrawerGestureModeAll];
```

when you push any view cancel gesture using below code.

```
[self.mm_drawerController setOpenDrawerGestureModeMask:MMOpenDrawerGestureModeNone];
```

Comment: I Imported MMDrawerController in the View Controller in which I want to use and I added the code in the ViewWillAppear method MMDrawerController * drawer;                             self.drawer = [[MMDrawerController alloc] init];
    [self.drawer setOpenDrawerGestureModeMask:MMOpenDrawerGestureModeNone]; But it did not worked slide menu is still accessible from this View Controller

Comment: Yeah it worked I did not made new object for MMDrawerController I just imported AppDelegate and overwrite drawerController object in my View Controller and called the method setOpenDrawerGestureModeMask with argument  MMOpenDrawerGestureModeNone

Comment: @pawandeepsingh sorry for late reply. now its working or not? you have to import all classes.

Comment: @pawandeepsingh if this answer is helpful and solve  your problem then accept it as and answer or upvote.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want side menu for a view controller, call it using segue

example issue code:

assuming you have used this code in the side menu to navigate to other view controllers

```
switch(item selected) ....
case number:
centerViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"STORYBOARD_ID"];
```

instead use :

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue_identifier" sender:nil];
```

this will navigate to completely new context instead of adding your view controllers to the centerViewController of MMDrawerController